# Why Redirect is not working in laravel 8, when I click on the button view not redirect to view.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I don't understand why Redirect() is not working when I click on the button view not redirect to view.blade.php

```
    public function view($id)
    {
        $orders = Order::where('id', $id)->where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
        return view('frontend.orders.view', compact('orders'));
        
    }
```

```
<a href="{{ url('view-order/'.$item->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
```

```
Route::get('view-order', [UserController::class, 'view']);
```

Comment: your route and target url is not same, your target url has a parameter that not mentioned on route

Comment: Route::get('view-order/{id}', [UserController::class, 'view']);   I'm try this one but not working

Answer (score 0):

You should add the url parameter to the route definition.

```
Route::get('view-order/{id}', [UserController::class, 'view']);
```

For a more strict approach to routes, you can use route naming instead.

```
Route::get('view-order/{id}', [UserController::class, 'view'])
    ->name('orders.view');
```

Now you can refer to your route as so, this would have meant, you would have hit the correct route url. If you define the parameter it expects is as the second input on the route() call.

```
<a href="{{ route('orders.view', $item->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
```

Comment: Route::get('view-order/{id}', [UserController::class, 'view']); I'm try this one but still not working

Comment: erm... you got more than one route starting with view-order?

Comment: The route starting with view-order have only 1

Comment: Firstly what happens when you click the link, what is the output of php artisan route:list, we need some more info to help from here.

Comment: URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/view-order/5, with message 404 Not Found,  when I clicked on the view button

Comment: ok as said what is the output of php artisan route:list?